# JMSException from weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

I wrote Sender class, where I'm preparing and sending messages. After prepare, I call session.commit() and catch this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weblogic.logging.Loggable.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;I[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Lweblogic/i18n/logging/MessageLogger;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
        at weblogic.jms.JMSClientExceptionLogger.logNoTransaction3Loggable(JMSClientExceptionLogger.java:1738)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.commit(JMSSession.java:1228)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.commit(JMSSession.java:1213)
        at weblogic.jms.client.WLSessionImpl.commit(WLSessionImpl.java:110)
```

So, what's wrong?
Code sample from my project:

```
    Contect ctx = new InitialContext();
     QueueConnectionFactory qcf =
(QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup(
"MyConnectionFactory");
     QueueConnection con = qcf.createQueueConnection();
    QueueSession session =
con.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Queue queue = null;
     try{
      queue = (Queue)ctx.lookup("MyQueue");
     }catch(NameNotFoundException nnfe){
       queue = session.createQueue("MyQueue");
      ctx.bind("MyQueue",queue);
    }
TextMessage textMessage =
session.createTextMessage();
     QueueSender sender =
session.createSender(queue);
     con.start(); 
       textMessage.setText("Hi! It's my message number "+i);
sender.send(textMessage);
session.commit();
```

UPD: Sender class'es code

Comment: Can you show your sender class please.

Comment: @Johnv2020 sure, look at the code sample. I updated it.

Comment: What does your classpath look like? It's like you're missing OR have two versions of the same class on your classpath. `weblogic.logging.Loggable` exists in wlfullclient.jar, wlclient.jar, wlthint3client.jar....